# Is rosversion broken on Groovy?

Tags: ros, rosdistro, remote-roscore, rosversion, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently, I've noticed problems with **rosversion** on Groovy:

```
$ rosversion roslaunch
Cannot locate [roslaunch]
```

It works with the -d flag, and it works on Hydro. I suspect my problem started around the time of the new **rosdistro** release.

Unfortunately, **roscore** runs that exact command, and exits when it fails.

Am I the only one seeing this?

**UPDATE**: I seem to have **python-rospkg** 1.0.20-1, probably from shadow-fixed. That must be the problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61981/is-rosversion-broken-on-groovy?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-05-02**:
rospkg is always deployed with the same version in all three repos - building, shadow-fixed and ros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Piyush and I figured it out this afternoon. You're going to love this!

We had released a 3rd-party **libfreenect** package to Groovy. As suggested by the bloom tutorial, we added a `package.xml`, with this install command:

```
install(FILES package.xml DESTINATION share/${PROJECT})
```

Apparently, `${PROJECT}` was not defined in that CMake file, so the file got installed directly in `/opt/ros/groovy/share`, instead of the desired `/opt/ros/groovy/share/libfreenect`. That had the unexpected effect of hiding *all* the wet Groovy packages, since `package.xml` is never resolved in a package subdirectory.

Fortunately, this only affected the two of us, because we had installed **ros-groovy-libfreenect** from the ros-shadow-fixed repository. We will release a fix shortly.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It works for me:

```
dpkg -s python-rospkg | grep Version
  1.0.18-1
rosversion roslaunch
  1.9.44
```

Using ROS groovy, installed from latest debian packages from the primary release repository.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-02**:
Thanks, that helps. I suspect the newer rosversion in shadow-fixed is the culprit. Issue here: https://github.com/ros/rospkg/issues/37

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Working for me, with the latest python-rospkg:

```
$ dpkg -l python-rospkg python-rosdistro ros-groovy-roslaunch
ii  python-rospkg  1.0.20-1       ROS package library
ii  python-rosdist 0.2.8-1        A tool to work with rosdistro files
ii  ros-groovy-ros 1.9.44-0precis roslaunch is a tool for easily launching mul
$ rosversion roslaunch
1.9.44
```

Is there something funny elsewhere on your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH? Can you roscd roslaunch?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-02**:
No, I can't. Even when I source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash directly. ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is /opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-02**:
I have the same versions of those three packages.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-05-02**:
Is roslaunch in /opt/ros/groovy/share ? Is there an /opt/ros/groovy/roslaunch/package.xml on your system?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-02**:
Yes it is.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2013-05-02**:
I'm out of actual ideas, so I'll start throwing out the usual Linux-isms: is your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH set and exported? Try: sh -c 'echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH' . Permissions problems? Are you executing the rosversion from /usr/bin/rosversion ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to have `roslaunch` in your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` so that it can be found. `rosversion` does not work with `rosdistro`, it works locally. So, if it cannot find the package locally then it will fail like that:

```
% rosversion roslaunch
Cannot locate [roslaunch]

% groovy  # alias to source ~/groovy/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.zsh

% rosversion roslaunch
1.9.41
```

**EDIT:**

The problem is that you have most likely unset or otherwise changed your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` such that `roscore` is on the `PATH` and `roslaunch` is on the `PYTHON_PATH`, but `roslaunch` is not on the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.

**EDIT:**

Also make sure that `rospkg` is not installed via pip, an older version in pip might be overriding the version of `rospkg` which is getting used. You can double check the version like this:

```
python
>>> import rospkg
>>> rospkg.__version__
0.1.19
>>> rospkg.__file__
/some/path/which/should/be/under/usr/not/usr/local
```

And:

```
which rosversion
```

Should return somewher in `/usr/` not `/usr/local/`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-02**:
I directly sourced /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash. ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is /opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-02**:
I have to think then that your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is getting messed up at run time then, I just read through the code and the only way you get that message is if roslaunch is not on your RPP.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-02**:
Also, the code path is entirely within rospkg, it doesn't depend on rosdep or rosdistro to run.

**Comment by [Nigel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5623/nigel/) on 2013-08-01**:
So my rospkg.**file** is in /usr/local/ how do I change it to /usr/ ?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-08-01**:
If you're on Ubuntu, do `sudo pip uninstall rospkg` until it doesn't uninstall anything, then do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-rospkg`

**Comment by [Nigel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5623/nigel/) on 2013-08-01**:
Thanks William, that did the job

**Comment by [Nigel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5623/nigel/) on 2013-08-02**:
Booted the computer up today and rospkg is in '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rospkg/**init**.pyc'
but rosversion is in /usr/local/bin/rosversion. How do I know get rosversion in the correct directory ?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-08-03**:
There should be another copy in `/usr/bin/rosversion`, if there is you can remove the one in `/usr/local/bin/rosversion`.

**Comment by [Nigel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5623/nigel/) on 2013-08-04**:
Thanks William really appreciated you trying to help me out, but this is what worked

This is caused by having a previously-installed "pip" version of rospkg which is out of date.

Fix this by:

sudo pip uninstall rospkg

repeat this until it says "not found"

then to be sure you have the latest:

sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install python-rospkg

The "pip uninstall" version is supposed to work, but personally I did:

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin* sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ros* sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ros* sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/catkin*

to remove the old pip-installed versions. This should be safe for both Fuerte and Groovy users, because these tools are all now installed to /usr/ instead of /usr/local and are available as debian packages.

I stole this from another post by Hersh https://www.google.com.au/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=problem+rosversion&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=ZlX-Uf_kIaaViQelm4Ew